# Recursive block arrangement pattern.

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

I'm allowed to only use three blocks ([these ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2KZG.png)) and only use the corner pieces together, to build different shapes of height $3$ and variable width.

I'm tasked with finding a recursive pattern for the number of arrangements of width $1, 2, 3, 4. . .$.

I've drawn out the number of arrangements for the first 4 widths:([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmxgd.png)) but I cannot seem to figure out the pattern.

I realize that:

- Starting with all the shapes of width $1$, you can combine shapes of width $3$ in $17$ different ways to build the shapes of width $4$,
- Starting with all the shapes of width $2$, you can make all the shapes of width $4$ (which is $21$)
- Starting with all the shapes of width $3$, it's the same as all the shapes as width $1$.

I do not see a specific (recursive) pattern here, can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I expect that rotation of the blocks is not permitted. Otherwise, the two L blocks are the same and you are using only two distinct blocks.

Comment: As far as recursion with rotations, you can extend a pattern by 1, 2 or 3 units in various ways. Note that an extension of two or three units should not include anything that could be a lesser extension of a longer pattern.

Comment: The only requirement with the L blocks is when I use one, I have to use the other to fit it to make it into a 2 x 4 block.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Using this information, you can define base cases $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 10$, and then the number of arrangements of width $n \ge 4$, $=f(n) = f(n-1) + 2f(n-2) + 5f(n-3)$.